# a way to restore the native escape function after it has been overwritten?

Tags: javascript

I didn't know you could do this until I had banged my head against the wall on a troublesome bug and finally figured out we were failing because some jquery plugin had overwritten the escape function.  So this will put up an alert and docwrite null:

```
escape = function(a){alert(a)}
document.write(escape("Need tips? Visit W3Schools!"));
```

Cool! (not).

Is there a way to restore the native escape function?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, it would be best to ditch the plugin or fix it but it is outside the scope I have control of.  I think I will be able
save the old escape and restore it.

Answer (score 13):

Create an iframe and get the function from it:

```
function retrieveNative(native) {
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  var retrieved = iframe.contentWindow[native];
  document.body.removeChild(iframe);
  return retrieved;
}

window.escape = retrieveNative('escape');
```

Comment: Keep in mind that it is, for some functions, important to be attached to the `window` object: e.g. window.getSelection will not work otherwise.

Comment: I'm amazed that this works and suffers no cross domain issues. Nice find!

Comment: @Scharrels: you can still use apply and bind to run the functions with window as the "this" object.

Comment: This is not actually going to work as modern browsers destroy the objects on removed windows for garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

Throw that plugin away because you don't know what evil lurks in there. If you can't do that, then the most optimal solution is to put up a `var` keyword before escape so it doesn't leak to the global scope and stays within the plugin function.

```
$.fn.naughtyJQueryPlugin = function() {
    var escape = function() { .. };
};
```

<strike>If you can't modify the plugin source, then wrap code around the plugin to hold on to a reference to the original escape, that you can fix later.</strike>

```
var origEscape = escape;

$.fn.naughtyJQueryPlugin = function() {
    ...
};

escape = origEscape;
```

---

Thanks to @Tim pointing out, here's a more robust technique if you can wrap around the plugin source:

```
(function(escape) {
    $.fn.naughtyJQueryPlugin = function() {
        // any change to escape (not window.escape) will affect the parameter
        // we passed in the outer function to which we have a reference 
        // through a closure.
        // This avoids manipulating the plugin's source, and still have both
        // versions intact.
    };
})(escape); // pass the global escape as a parameter

// should call the global escape
escape("hello");

// when plugin is called, overridden escape should be called
$("div").naughtyJQueryPlugin("message");
```

See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fLc6a/). Both versions should co-exist peacefully.

Comment: In the latter case, that is likely to clobber the plug-in: it will redefine `escape` inside the function, then escape wuill be immediately reset to its original value, and then calls to `naughtyJQueryPlugin` will use the original escape function rather than the plug-in's version.

Comment: @Tim - thanks for the tip. A closure would probably better solve the problem. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add your code before the plugin - you can "save" the original function:

```
oldescape = escape;
function fix() {
    escape = oldescape;
}
```